# How to make auto update into mysql through php

Tags: php

We have a table in database called validity and update 'inactive' automatically into database when validity will expire by current date

```
validity_from | validity_to | status
------------------------------------
28-05-2019    | 28-06-2019  | active
------------------------------------
```

How can i achieve this function in php

Please suggest and help me.

Comment: Why do you want to store this redundant information in the first place? The validity of any record can be determined on the fly whenever you read the data. Much less chance of things going sideways, because such an “automatic update” might fail at some point.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a cron job that runs in background and update 'status' filed accordingly

Comment: How can i do that. Do you have any references for that?

Comment: check this link hope it will help you `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php    ` `https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428`